# Babel settings to deal with new React create class warnings

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I started getting the following warning in React V 15.4.2.

> React.createClass is deprecated and will be removed in version 16. Use
>   plain JavaScript classes instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate,
>   create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.

My JSX file is below. The culprit seems to be the settings I am using for Babel, What settings should I use: (as you can see this is a electron v1.4 app

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-preset-node7": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": ">=1.4.15",
    "electron-packager": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "node7"
    ]
  }
```

Dashboard.jsx

```
const React = require('react')
const { Component } = require('react')
const {} = require('react-bootstrap')
import { App, Title, Section, Header, Footer, Columns, Box, Button } from 'grommet'


export const Page = props => (
  <App>
    <Title>Dashboard Version 1.0, Node version: xxx</Title>
    <Section>Status Section
      <p>Status: {props.serverState}</p>
    </Section>
    <Section >{/*  colorIndex='neutral-1' */ }
      <Header>Controls</Header>
      <Columns>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Install' onClick={props.installAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='UnInstall' onClick={props.uninstallAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Start' onClick={props.startAct}></Button>
        </Box>
        <Box pad='small'>
        <Button label='Stop' onClick={props.stopAct}></Button>
        </Box>
      </Columns>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Header>Config</Header>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Header>Cleanup</Header>
    </Section>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </App>
)
```

Comment: Babel is not translating your classes to `React.createClass`. This is more likely the same issue like in your previous question. One of your dependencies is using `React.createClass`.

Comment: Bable only converts JSX to `React.createElement` calls. It doesn't do anything with your component definitions (of course it converts classes to ES5).

Comment: @FelixKling I do see that babel does creat   React.createElement() , I was under the impression that that was also giving rise to the React.createClass warning. Can you confirm that I was wrong about that?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong about that :) [See the online REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3Ehello%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&playground=true)

Comment: I agree, it is a duplicate, but since there were different warnings, I broke it into two parts. Thanks @Sulthan